# Crystal Report "The Handle is Invalid" and "The remote procedure call failed" on PrintToPrinter (C#)

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, printers

we are getting error "The handle is invalid" when we call the PrintToPrinter function of CryslaReport ReportDocument. This error is not coming always. when we try to print huge numbe rof documents then only we are getting this.
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll  = 13.0.23.2819

at System.Drawing.Printing.StandardPrintController.OnStartPage(PrintDocument document, PrintPageEventArgs e)     at System.Drawing.Printing.PrintController.PrintLoop(PrintDocument document)     at System.Drawing.Printing.PrintController.Print(PrintDocument document)     at System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument.Print()     at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.FormatEngine.PrintToPrinter(PrinterSettings printerSettings, PageSettings pageSettings, PrintLayoutSettings layoutSettings, Boolean reformatReportPageSettings)     at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.PrintToPrinter(PrinterSettings printerSettings, PageSettings pageSettings, PrintLayoutSettings layoutSettings, Boolean reformatReportPageSettings)     at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.PrintToPrinter(PrinterSettings printerSettings, PageSettings pageSettings, Boolean reformatReportPageSettings)     at Workers.PrintWorker.OnDoWork(DoWorkEventArgs e) in E:\Workers\PrintWorker.cs:line 114

Sometimes we are also getting exception : The remote procedure call failed

StackTrace : at System.Drawing.Printing.StandardPrintController.OnStartPrint(PrintDocument document, PrintEventArgs e)     at System.Drawing.Printing.PrintController.Print(PrintDocument document)     at System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument.Print()     at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.FormatEngine.PrintToPrinter(PrinterSettings printerSettings, PageSettings pageSettings, PrintLayoutSettings layoutSettings, Boolean reformatReportPageSettings)     at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.PrintToPrinter(PrinterSettings printerSettings, PageSettings pageSettings, PrintLayoutSettings layoutSettings, Boolean reformatReportPageSettings)     at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.PrintToPrinter(PrinterSettings printerSettings, PageSettings pageSettings, Boolean reformatReportPageSettings)     at Workers.PrintWorker.OnDoWork(DoWorkEventArgs e) in E:\Workers\PrintWorker.cs:line 114

```
if (Service.Instance.Processors[_processor].Document != null) //here Document is CrystalReport ReportDocument object
{
    using (PrintDocument document = new PrintDocument())
    {
        PageSettings page = document.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings;
        PrinterSettings printer = document.PrinterSettings;
        //
        printer.Copies = Convert.ToInt16(_destination.ReportRequestHeader.Copies);
        printer.PrinterName = _destination.PrinterTypePrinter.Printer.QueueName;
        if (printer.PaperSources.Count > 1)
        {
            PaperSource tray = printer.PaperSources.Cast<PaperSource>()
                .Where(s => s.RawKind.Equals(Converter.ToInt32(_destination.PrinterTypePrinter.PaperTray)))
                .FirstOrDefault();
            if (tray != null) page.PaperSource = tray;
        }
        //
        Service.Instance.Processors[_processor].Document.PrintToPrinter(printer, page, false); //Getting error at this line
    }
}
```

anyone has any idea on these exceptions ?  NOTE: this is not always, its coming only when the load is high.

Comment: Hi, are you sure that the printer and page arguments being passed to PrintToPrinter() are not null? or whether that is handled in the method? would be good if we can see that method code as well

Comment: Hi, @NamrataP,, thank you for replying. printer and page arguments are present and being passed to PrintToPrinter() and they are not null.